# transport.Roundtrip context canceled error

Tags: http, go

I made a roundtrip in client, and I set a retry for 1 time. Question is sometimes my client triggered "context canceled", and entire processing seems like end in 300ms, but I didn't set a timeout. how is it triggered?

```
func RoundTrip(req *http.Request)(res *http.Response, err error){
    for i:=0; i<1; i++ {
        transport = http.DefaultTransport
        res, err = transport.RoundTrip(req)
        if err == nil {
             break;
        }
    }
    
    return 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the context to the request with the [Request.WithContext](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.WithContext) method or [NewRequestWithContext](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestWithContext) function. When you cancel the context it should propagate to all functions handling the request.

#### Update

Sorry I thought you wanted to cancel the request, not asking why. Anyhow given your comment on this answer:

> but where canceled the context in 300ms

300ms is pretty short. If it was longer I would recommend adjusting the timers in `net.DefaultTransport`; however, instead I would guess that the underlying TCP connection is being refused/limited and causing the RoundTrip to fail. TCP limit could be something internal (DNS lookup error, etc) or on the server side. You would need to scope the problem more to debug.

Comment: I will try, but where canceled the context in 300ms?

Comment: updated answer given your comment

Comment: Thanks for patience, It is strange that the two requests (retried) will stop at 300ms if the requests have be canceled. In other words, if the first request cost 299ms and get context canceled, the second one will cost about 1ms if it's alos be canceled. I used  the default config of `net.DefaultTransport` with 30s timeout. But instead if the request isn't be canceled, it can cost more or less than 300 ms.